# Wordcloud on a Marathi Corpus

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, word-cloud

https://mindurmarathi.com/b/

For my sentiment analysis in using Marathi tweets is a project I am working on, where I am trying to find out and research on how ML and Deep learning models may work for a low resource language.
I am trying to create a word cloud to visualize the word frequencies in the data set.

The data set looks like:

[image: These are tweets extracted and annotated manually into three levels of hierarchical classes.]

The word cloud code snippet I have tried:

```
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
tweet = data.tweet[0]
print((tweet))
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(tweet)

plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

and the output looks like this:

[image: word cloud output]

The output I am looking for as you can expect is not up to the expectation.
How can I produce a wordcloud for Marathi dataset.
Are there any libraries involved?
Should I write the word cloud generation script from scratch?
Please provide me with any resources and details for this task.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? And, can you try decoding the text in "utf-8", like `tweet = tweet.decode("utf-8")`.

Comment: Iam using python 3.8.5 . I tried that but I get an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` I tried `tweet = tweet.encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8") ` yielded the same result.